# How to fix Unhandled exception: java.sql.SQLException for throw sqle

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio

As a part of my app(API 11) I need to provide a predefined database and I found a tutorial online. So here is the java code but I get an error "Unhandled exception: java.sql.SQLException" on (throw sqle;).

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks for your time

```
package com.wima.twomatrixlibrarisampletest;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main210Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Cursor c = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main210);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button01)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Main210Activity.this);
            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error ("Unable to create database");
            }
            try {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
            Toast.makeText (Main210Activity.this, "Plz Work!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            c = myDbHelper.query("EMP_TABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Toast.makeText(Main210Activity.this, "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                                    "E_Flange: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                    "E_Web: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                                    "E_Ratio: " + c.getString(3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exceptions's message? What does sqle.getMessage() return?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't get `SQLExceptions` in android. You would get [`SQLiteException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html) if at all.

Comment: Please go and read a Java Tutorial.  This is really basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions come in two types Handled and Runtime.

Handled exceptions Must be caught(Try Catch) or thrown (throws)

Example **SQLException**, **IOExeption**

Runtime Exceptions can be caught but they do not need to be declared as thrown.

example: **OutOfMemoryException**,  **IndexOutOfBoundsException**.

SQLException is a Handled Exception so as the other answer declared you either have to surround your call in a try catch block to handle the exception or declare

```
public void onClick(View v) throws SqlException {
```

In your case, you are catching it then rethrowing it, this means that the method has to declare it as thrown which sort of defeats the object of the try catch, usually unless you need to throw it up, you should log the error then silently continue, in your case you are declaring throw e; which is just literally throwing the problem up a level, and to do that you need to as previously mentioned - declare that the method throws it The throw new Error() is a runtime exception so it does not need to be declared, So if you don't want to have to declare it thrown you could try something like

```
throw new Error(sqle.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 2):

My "idea how to fix" is: **study** the essential java basics before doing further android / database work!

A good starting point could be [The Java lesson about exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

You see, that method your code sits in is declared as:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

[ no throws clause ! ]

But yet you want to place a

```
throws sql exception
```

within that method! That simply can't work! The compiler is telling you that your code has to deal with that checked exception. You see, the signature of that method doesn't include any throws clauses, and you can't have it both ways. Either empty throws clause, then no throw calls; or throw calls; but then you would need a throws clause on the method!

In other words: your idea of just rethrowing that caught exception

1. makes no sense
2. is simply incorrect - because the enclosing method doesn't allow you to *throw* a checked exception that is not listed in the `throws` clause of the onClick method.

And of course: as you are *overriding* that method, you can't simply change it to

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) throws SqlException
```

As the "Android" folks **do not want** your code to throw checked exceptions.

Long story short: instead of blindly rethrowing that exception, you have to find *other* ways to deal with that failure! And in order to do that; you should first educate yourself about the things you are doing. Because as your code looks right now, it seems that you are pulling together ideas (probably from sites such as this) hoping to end up with something working. And hint: that will **not** work. You will run from one compiler error into the next one; and even when you get things to compile, your app will keep crashing all the time. Because, as said, you don't have much clue what your doing. And that is always a route to disaster.

Answer (score 1):

**Just extend your try/catch till database transaction ends :**

```
 try {
     .....
     .....
      Toast.makeText (Main210Activity.this, "Plz Work!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        c = myDbHelper.query("EMP_TABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Toast.makeText(Main210Activity.this, "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                                "E_Flange: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                "E_Web: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                                "E_Ratio: " + c.getString(3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
 catch(SQLException e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: He already has a try/catch. He **re throws** from the catch. Your answer is sorry, not helping, and the part you just added about adding a throws clause in is **utter** nonsense because that is **not** possible when overriding methods!

Comment: @GhostCat : i mean this line             c = myDbHelper.query("EMP_TABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
 in the code is not covered in try catch

Comment: Then fix your answer to say what you mean. So far, it doesnt really relate to his question, and **gives** wrong advise.

Comment: Well, you got a bunch of code, but no explanations whatsoever. So, no more downvote, but dont expect upvotes for something like that.